# Connection timeout error retrofit android

Tags: android, rest, retrofit

I am using Retrofit. The server is responding with correct data but when I implemented the stuff on app it's not working.

```
01-28 22:24:58.546: I/System.out(30595): [CDS]EAGAIN or EWOULDBLOCK in Recvfrom
01-28 22:24:58.546: I/System.out(30595): [CDS]read byte is 0
01-28 22:24:58.547: I/System.out(30595): [CDS]close[49674]
01-28 22:24:58.547: I/System.out(30595): close [socket][/0.0.0.0:49674]
01-28 22:24:58.556: I/System.out(30595): propertyValue:false
01-28 22:26:45.144: I/System.out(30595): [socket][5] connection ranics.com/104.219.248.39:80;LocalPort=52147(15000)
01-28 22:26:45.144: I/System.out(30595): [CDS]connect[raionics.com/104.219.248.39:80] tm:15
01-28 22:26:45.145: D/Posix(30595): [Posix_connect Debug]Process com.example.rainfinal_retro :80 
01-28 22:26:46.445: I/System.out(30595): [socket][/192.168.0.101:52147] connected
01-28 22:26:46.445: I/System.out(30595): [CDS]rx timeout:20000
01-28 22:26:47.022: I/System.out(30595): [socket][/192.168.0.101:52226] connected
01-28 22:26:47.022: I/System.out(30595): [CDS]rx timeout:20000
01-28 22:26:48.824: I/System.out(30595): [socket][6:59646] exception
01-28 22:26:48.824: I/System.out(30595): [CDS]close[59646]
```

Please suggest me some solution to this problem, of timeout error or whatever it is.
Do you guys have any idea is it related to opening the ports on server ?

Note: I have edited the DNS of my server on stackoverflow.

Comment: Could you post your Retrofit interface?

Comment: @Rahul Do you found solution to this problem?